# Docker build not finding nuget package from local directory

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio

I have a nuget package stored on my local filesystem at C:\Temp. When I add the nuget package to my Visual Studio Solution everything builds as expected.  However when I run my docker build command, I receive this error:

```
 MyProject depends on NugetExample.DLL (>= 0.0.4) but NugetExample.DLL 0.0.4 was not found.
```

Heres a copy of my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build
WORKDIR /build
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 3000


COPY . .

# Restore/build...
# Use debug publish when you need to debug the service running in docker
RUN dotnet publish src/app/MyProject.csproj -c Debug -o /app



# Stage 2
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
RUN sed -i -e "s|^MinProtocol = .*|MinProtocol = TLSv1.0|g" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Is there a way to get docker to find my nuget package stored on my local filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull a NuGet from your local filesystem it needs to be in your Docker build context: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/

Alternatively, you can use the new dotnet publish support for making a container image (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container) which does a local build and then copies it into a container image for you. One caveat for your use, to get maintain the effect of:

```
RUN sed -i -e "s|^MinProtocol = .*|MinProtocol = TLSv1.0|g" "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"
```

You would need to create a base image based on your current stage 2 and then configure publish to use it with [ContainerBaseImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container#containerbaseimage)